# "originated" or "was originated"

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> The first calendar **was originated** in Egypt.
>
> The first calendar **originated** in Egypt.

Which voice is suitable for the word "originate", active or passive voice?

Comment: The first calendar**s** originated in Egypt. [note plural]

Comment: @Mick I fail to see what pluralization has to do with the question.

Answer (score 13):

[Originate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/originate) is used as an intransitive verb here.

> to take or have origin

That (generally) means it can't be used in passive form.